# Restrict move-able character withing screens bounds on a webpage

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have a moveable character on a webpage but I want prevent it from going out of the screen's bounds.

I have added some code below, but basically i want to prevent the image from moving off screen, It must stop at the end of screen width/height.
(use arrow keys to control image).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("This page has loaded!");
 
    //Below is code which hides a paragraph when the button is clicked
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide("slow", function(){
            alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
        });
    });
        //let width  =Math.max($(document).width(), $(window).width());
        //let height=Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height());
        let height=$(window).height();
        let width=$(window).width();
    //Below is code which allows for the character to move - why not try craft your own version?
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        // document.write(Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height()));
        //  document.write(Math.max($(document).width(), $(window).width()));
 
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
            // Left arrow key pressed
            case 37:
                if($('img').position().left>0){
                    $('img').animate({left: "-=20px"}, 'fast');}
                  
//             else{
              
 
                    break;
            // Up Arrow Pressed
            case 38:
                $('img').animate({top: '-=20px'},'fast');
                break;
            // Right Arrow Pressed
            case 39:
if($('img').position().left<width){
                $('img').animate({left: '+=20px'},'fast');}
                break;
            // Down Arrow Pressed
            case 40:
                $('img').animate({top: '+=20px'},'fast');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
background: cyan;
overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script> <!--Including jQuery -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script> <!-- Including the scripting file -->
</head>

<body>
<img  src="http://staublicht.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/walk_animation.gif"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about before you animate the image, you check if it would end up off the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path with your first `case` statement:

```
if($('img').position().left>0) {
  ...
}
```

but you are checking if the current position is greater than 0 instead of checking if the **new position** will be greater than 0.

So instead:

```
if($('img').position().left - 20 > 0) {
   ...
}
```

and do the same thing for the *top*, *right*, and *bottom* `case` statements as well.

One problem you'll run into is if the user holds down the key for an extended period of time the image will move past the screen because the `keydown` listener will trigger multiple times while the image hasn't caught up to the correct position due the animations. You'll probably want to prevent `keydown` while the image is moving.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("This page has loaded!");

    //Below is code which hides a paragraph when the button is clicked
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide("slow", function(){
            alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
        });
    });
        //let width  =Math.max($(document).width(), $(window).width());
        //let height=Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height());
        let height=$(window).height();
        let width=$(window).width();
    //Below is code which allows for the character to move - why not try craft your own version?
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        // document.write(Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height()));
        //  document.write(Math.max($(document).width(), $(window).width()));

        console.log(parseInt(key.which,10));
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
            // Left arrow key pressed
            case 37:
                if ($('img').position().left - 20 > 0) {
                  $('img').animate({left: "-=20px"}, 'fast');
                }
                break;
            // Up Arrow Pressed
            case 38:
                if ($('img').position().top - 20 > 0) {
                  $('img').animate({top: '-=20px'},'fast');
                }
                break;
            // Right Arrow Pressed
            case 39:
                if($('img').position().left + $('img').width() + 20 < width) {
                  $('img').animate({left: '+=20px'},'fast');
                  }
                break;
            // Down Arrow Pressed
            case 40:
                if ($('img').position().top + $('img').height() + 20 < height) {
                  $('img').animate({top: '+=20px'},'fast');
                }
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/608933/)

Comment: I've tried that but i don't think I'm implementing it correctly, is it possible for you to give me a practical version

Comment: Fiddle provided at the bottom.